# Converting standard HTML and JS to work in email

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have created the following HTML for use in sending emails. I was wondering how I would get this to work so that style rules for the images were followed along with the rules for the grey background in the header and footer.

```css
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 6vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}

.headerandfooter {
background-color: #5c5c5c;
width: 100%;
}

body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.headerlogo {
max-width: 40%; 
padding:2vh;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
object-fit: contain;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.headerlogo {
max-width: 60%; 
padding:2vh;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
object-fit: contain;
}
</style>

<style>
.icons {
width: 10%;
max-width: 10%; 
padding:1vh;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.icons {
width: 30%;
max-width: 30%; 
padding:1vh;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
}

.col-container {
display: table;
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 1vh;
background-color: #5c5c5c;
}

.column {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}

h6 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 1vw;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h6 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 3vw;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 1vh;
padding-right: 1vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="Style Will Be Linked" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="headerandfooter">
<img class="headerlogo" src="LOGO" draggable="false" alt="Logo">
</div>
<br>

<div class="emailcontent">
<h1>Email Header</h1>
<p>Email Test Content</p>
</div>

<br>
<div class="headerandfooter">
<div class="col-container">
<div class="column">
<a href="ICON1URL"> <img class="icons" src="ICON1IMGURL" draggable="false" alt="ICON1"></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
<a href="ICON2URL"> <img class="icons" src="ICON2IMGURL" draggable="false" alt="ICON2"> </a>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h6>©<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script><br><br></h6>
</div>
</div>
```

If you run it, the code does work on web but doesn't correctly render in email, the images do display but none of the CSS does.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: emails don't do `<head>` tags or external stylesheets; you'll need to include everything inline

Comment: also, margins and fonts are generally problematic. Don't forget that every email client is different, so something that works in gmail might not work in hotmail or outlook or applemail

Comment: HTML Emails are quite different from web pages. Email clients are even less consistent than browsers when it come to implantation. You need to keep it simple and table based layout even comes into play (yes I feel dirty just saying that). As for javascript, most email clients don't support it at all, so don't even bother.

Answer (score 0):

Many email client's such as (Outlook, Yahoo, Gmail) will stripe away styles unless inline. Styles must be inline for email templates to render properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 6vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    }

    .headerandfooter {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    width: 100%;
    }

    body, html {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 0vw;
        margin: 0vw;
    }

    .headerlogo {
    max-width: 40%; 
    padding:2vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .headerlogo {
    max-width: 60%; 
    padding:2vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
    }
    </style>
    .icons {
    width: 10%;
    max-width: 10%; 
    padding:1vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .icons {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 30%; 
    padding:1vh;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    }

    .col-container {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1vh;
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    }

    .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    }

    h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    }

    h6 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h6 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    }
</style>
<div class="headerandfooter">
<img class="headerlogo" src="LOGO" draggable="false" alt="Logo">
</div>
<br>

<div class="emailcontent">
<h1>Email Header</h1>
<p>Email Test Content</p>
</div>

<br>
<div class="headerandfooter">
<div class="col-container">
<div class="column">
<a href="ICON1URL"> <img class="icons" src="ICON1IMGURL" draggable="false" alt="ICON1"></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
<a href="ICON2URL"> <img class="icons" src="ICON2IMGURL" draggable="false" alt="ICON2"> </a>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h6>©<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script><br><br></h6>
</div>
</div>
</body>enter code here
```

Comment: Note that Media Query support is far from universal when it comes to email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Emails doesn't support regular CSS inside style tag and you cannot use few things like negative margins, absolute positions and few other stuff, they won't work in an email client. That is the reason, many people still use standard tables in emailers. you can use all the elements, but better have the styling inline to every particular element. Only system fonts are supported. Roboto would be available only on Android phones in case you choose to use it. all other devices default to serif. And Media queries won't work in emailers. You gotta use some hacks with sizes and floats to achieve what some people call responsive emailers. Emailer services Gmail/yahoo mail and clients outlook/apple mail etcetera will strip away all the external CSS which is not inline. And each of them may render things differently. when you try to email testing service with this code, all they do is strip the CSS and add it inline to your HTML.